# C# methods with variable paramterlist as parameter

Tags: c#

Hi I'm currently trying to pass methods (with no return value) as parameters to another method (so that they can be called from within the methods).

The problem I'm currently having is, that I'm using Action in the parameterlist and thus need to exactly define which parameters this method takes.

The question thus is: Is there any way to omit this? Thus that I don't have to define which parameters exactly the method has in the parameterdeclaration?

Codeexample:

```
public void A(int myint)
{
   Console.WriteLine(myint.ToString());
}

public void B(int myint1, int myint2)
{
   Console.WriteLine((myint1 + myint2).ToString());
}


public void myQuestionMethod(Action<int> parameterMethod)
{
    //....Dosomething special by creating the parameters within and calling the given methods
}


myQuestionMethod(A);
myQuestionMethod(B);
```

Thus Aciton parameterMethod can that be replaced by something else that allows me to give methods as parameters who have differing parameters?

Edit:
I forgot to mention that the TYPE of the parameters is also not fixated.

Thus a function C could exist with (int param1, String param2)

Comment: Is `myQuestionMethod<T>(Action<T> parameterMethod)` what you're looking for? Your question is a bit unclear.

Comment: It is how I have to declare the parameter (the function) in the parameterlist of myQuestionMethod what I'm looking for. Action I only mentioned there as a showcase as to how I had used it so far with 1 parameter for the methodToBeCalled and only 1 parameterType.

Answer (score 3):

No. There is no way to do this with the `Action` delegate (that's why there are 16 overloads).

You could opt, if the variables are all of the same type and have the same meaning, to create an array of integers:

```
public void A(params int[] myint)
{
}

public void myQuestionMethod(Action<int[]> parameterMethod)
{
    //....Dosomething special by creating the parameters within and calling the given methods
}
```

Comment: I updated the questoin (tnx for pointing it out with the int[] there). I can't tell for sure if the type of the parameter is the same (also Action itself is not mandatory, I only mentioned it in the examplecode as it was the variant I used for a fixated number of parameters so far)

Comment: I had a similar answer, only with a params array: public void A(params int[] myInts)

Comment: @ThomasE.: need more help?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how big your methods are, you could go for just `Action` and use anonymous methods rather than explicitly defining the functions

```
public void myQuestionMethod(Action parameterMethod)
{
    //
}
...
myQuestionMethod(() => Console.WriteLine(myInt.ToString()));
myQuestionMethod(() => Console.WriteLine((myInt1 + myInt2).ToString()));
```

Comment: Am I correct there taht that would start the methods already when they are passed as a parameter? (would there be a possibility to make it that they are not started immedieately but only later inside the myQuestionMEthod)?

Comment: @ThomasE. no the method is not executed as it's passed, you are simply declaring the body of the method, it's only executed when `parameterMethod` is explicitly called inside the method.

Comment: is there a possibility to add an parameter to the method before it is started? (thus inside myQuestionMethod)

Comment: @ThomasE. no, that's the whole point of it being an `Action`, there are no parameters. If you need to pass a parameters in then I suggest you use @PatrickHofman's approach.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to use reflection. Of course don't use it unless you do not have any other choice (specifying a method using its name should be avoided if possible):

```
public class Foo
{
    public void A(int myint)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(myint.ToString());
    }

    public void B(int myint1, int myint2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine((myint1 + myint2).ToString());
    }

    public void myQuestionMethod(string parameterMethodName, params object[] parameters)
    {
        var method = this.GetType().GetMethod(parameterMethodName, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
        method.Invoke(this, parameters);
    }
}

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var foo = new Foo();

        foo.myQuestionMethod("B", 1, 2);

        Console.Read();
    }
}
```